# Matrix vs Neo, what should you use for 60+ multi site

Tags: matrix, plugin-neo

Simple question: Which field type is more *performant*, Matrix or Neo?

I have to build a 60+ multi-site with different languages and I need to think about this architecture before building the *pageParts*.

Does anyone know which one of these fields uses fewer resources on the database?

Thank you

LE: I have found this:

*Performance
Out of the box, a Craft Matrix re-saves every block within that Matrix. If you have dozens of fields then this can take a lot of resources, meaning it takes a while to save. Ben (author of Neo) has built-in a superb feature in which the Neo field detects what is new and only saves the newly created content within the fields. Clever stuff!*

Is it true?

Comment: For such an enormous project, I would be much more concerned about stability/robustness/longevity, extensibility, and support options if things go wrong... I'm sure the Neo developers are wonderful in every regard, and will speedily update their plugin in line with changes to Craft and will never break core functionality or corrupt your content or expose your site to hackers, but personally I would never consider using a third-party plugin for such an integral part of your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your needs. If the features of the Matrix fields are enough for you, I'd definitely stick with Matrix. If you need nested or reusable blocks, then go for Neo.

Neo adds 4 tables to the database, so it must use it at some point and create a little overhead.

That being said, I think your primary focus to improve performance should be on implementing [eager-loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) ([Neo supports it too](https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-neo/blob/master/docs/eager-loading.md)), and, if it's not enough, leveraging the [`{% cache %}` twig tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#cache).

And as James Smith pointed, using a third-party plugin is always a risk to consider when working on a large project.

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider Vizy:
https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/vizy/features

Very performant and nice to use for your editors.